# XNA: How to measure the amount of time a key is held down for?

Tags: c#, xna, sprite

I'm trying to make a jumping mechanism in my game which will work  something like this:

// velocity.Y is the velocity of the sprite I want to jump

```
 if (keystate.IsKeyDown(Keys.W))
         {
             velocity.Y = 3 - (time elapsed since start of jump);
         }
```

I thought this might be a simple and elegant solution to making my sprite jump but if it is not possible like this just say so and it's back to the drawing board.

Comment: Give it an initial impulse, and keep adding velocity up as long as the key is pressed. Of course, the velocity you add is lower than the gravity. No need to count time or anything. Beside, speed or acceleration are always related to time anyway.

Comment: What do you mean by an initial impulse?

Comment: The initial impusle is the velocity at the moment you press the jump key. Basicly, you give velocity = 10 (up) and just keep the gravity pull back down. And that's it, the character jumped. If you want you jump to have air control or bigger reach when holding a key, you keep adding small bit of upward velocity.

Comment: the main problem I've been having is trying to give a limit to the jump height and to make it impossible for the player to simply float when holding the key down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest not connecting the physics so directly to the player input, it's not a very extendable architecture.

Have an interface which defines physics properties such as velocity which is implemented by your character object.  When the player presses the up-key you should check if the player is on the ground, if they are then set their acceleration to move up. Then have a physics system iterate through a list of every object which implements the physics interface applying gravity and other forces before moving the entities around. This way you can use the same physics code for every entity in your game.

I would also suggest not connecting keyboard input directly to the movement of the player. You can have an interface called 'ICharacterController' which defines a 'nextInstruction' method which returns 'CharacterInstructions' which defines various actions characters can take such as jumping and moving, this can be implemented by an input class. Your character class then holds a reference to a CharacterController so it just calls nextInstruction, this way the character can be controlled by Player Input, AI, or through network communication but still share the same behavior as the player.

[Game Coding Complete](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Game-Coding-Complete-Mike-McShaffry/dp/1133776574) is a brilliant book to read if you're serious about game programming.

I can also recommend [Game Engine Architecture](http://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/1568814135/ref=asc_df_156881413510514826?smid=A3P5ROKL5A1OLE&tag=googlecouk06-21&linkCode=asn&creative=22206&creativeASIN=1568814135)

As you're using XNA you should consider using [Game Components](http://sharpoverride.hubpages.com/hub/Xna-Tip-Organize-your-game-in-components)

Comment: Thanks for the information, good to know if I can be more efficient and professional with my approach. I'll have a look into that book. And you are definitely right, a physics system which effects the entire game would be much more helpful in the long run then just a temporary fix to get the player jumping.

Comment: No problem, I've just added a few more links for you.

Answer (score 0):

XNA doesn't have built-in methods to detect a press vs. a press-and-hold; it is only able to tell you if the key is *currently* being pressed.

What you need to do, then, is to store two KeyboardState-s, "Old" and "Current". Once you have this, you are able to detect when a keypress starts (`old.isKeyDown == false && current.isKeyDown == true;` ) and when it ends (`old.isKeyDown == true && current.isKeyDown == false;`

So once you have this, it's a simple matter to record a "jumpStart" variable based on the GameTime when you detect the keypress, and a "jumpEnd" variable from when you detect the key release.

If you want to base the duration of a jump on the amount of time the key is held down, you may be better served by setting up an upper limit, afterwhich further holding down of the key has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

not if that what you are looking for in another words if the  velocity function is executing while you hold the button but ou can use stopwath to measure that

```
Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
 if (keystate.IsKeyDown(Keys.W))
         {
             velocity.Y = 3 - (time elapsed since start of jump);
             stopWatch.Start();
         }
 if (keystate.IsKeyUp(Keys.W))
{
         stopWatch.Stop();
        TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;

}
```

more here

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2

Comment: This'll trigger stopWatch.Start() every frame the key is pressed. Does that matter? (I'm unfamiliar with stopWatch)

Comment: I believe the new instance shall start every time it pressed so it probably new time but you can always hod the time for each iteration